# Tomcat 7 Escape sequence

Tags: tomcat7, struts-1

Tomcat 7 double // append in html:form action value instead of single / please help me how to ignore it

```
<form name="WorkOrderForm" method="post" action="//WorkOrder.do" id="RequestFormID">
```

i want it to be like this:

```
<form name="WorkOrderForm" method="post" action="/WorkOrder.do" id="RequestFormID">
```

my jsp code is:

```
<html:form action="/WorkOrder.do" styleId="RequestFormID">
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your action attribute value can do without the "/".

Just do the following and it should still forward it to "/WorkOrder.do" url.

```
<html:form action="WorkOrder.do" styleId="RequestFormID">
```

Comment: Hi Susie , Thank you for your update i have tried above code without / also not working ,

Comment: Please put on your suggestions